# How to setup tomcat7 in ubuntu 14.04 so that it uses latest JRE of java-8-oracle?

Tags: java, ubuntu, servlets, tomcat7

when I compile a servlet using java-8-oracle in eclipse and put the classes file in tomcat7/webapps directory , I get a `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` error. But when I compile the version with JDK compliance 1.6 , the servlet runs just fine. Here are my outputs of different settings

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

the folders in /usr/lib/jvm

```
$ ls
default-java              java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  java-7-openjdk-amd64
java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64  java-6-openjdk-amd64      java-8-oracle
java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64  java-6-openjdk-common
```

Here is my /etc/environment file

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/ga mes:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

and lastly I appended this line `export JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"` to my .bashrc in home directory.

So how can I setup tomcat7 to use the java-8-oracle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
```

run these in terminal

EDIT 1
------[image]
run in terminal `sudo nano /etc/default/tomcat7` , uncomment line JAVA_HOME and change its value to JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle, and press cntrl+x , Y , ENTER to save the changed settings, now JAVA_HOME is set permanently for tomcat7

Comment: But then I have to run this  every time I start my PC

Comment: @TamimAdDari Save these commands in your .bash_rc or .profile file.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the contents of the

> .../apache_tomcat/bin/setenv.sh

```
 ...
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`
...
```